# How to configure IBM MQ v9 to use Microsoft AD for user authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, ibm-mq

I'm trying to set up Microsoft AD like user repository for IBM MQ v9 Queue Manager , but without success. I read the document https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085490_.htm, but it's very unclear with all those diagrams, dashes and arrows. My final goal is to have ability to grant or rewoke authorizations based od AD groups. Can someone give me complete commands example how to configure queue manager to use AD for user repository?

IBM MQ is v9.0.0.0 and runs on CentOS v7. Active Directory is on Windows Server 2019 machine.

I tried to set AUTHINFO with MQSC commands. All commands are executed without problems. After that I refreshed security and tried to grant authorizations with setmqaut command, but unsuccessful.

I tried with this below MQSC commands:

```
DEFINE AUTHINFO(MY.AD.CONFIGURATION) AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP) AUTHORMD(SEARCHGRP) FINDGRP(member) CONNAME('192.168.100.100') BASEDNG('OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us') SHORTUSR('sAMAccountName') LDAPUSER('mybinduser') LDAPPWD('mypassword')

ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(MY.AD.CONFIGURATION)

REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)

setmqaut -m MY.QUEUE.MANAGER -t qmgr -g myadgroup +all
```

After I execute command:
`setmqaut -m MY.QUEUE.MANAGER -t qmgr -g myadgroup +all`

This error is displyed i console: `AMQ7026: A principal or group name was invalid.`

And these below lines are recorded in queue manager log:

```
AMQ5531: Error locating user or group in LDAP

EXPLANATION:
The LDAP authentication and authorization service has failed in the ldap_search
call while trying to find user or group 'myadgroup '. Returned count is 0.
Additional context is 'rc = 87 (Bad search filter)
[(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(=myadgroup ))]'.
ACTION:
Specify the correct name, or fix the directory configuration. There may be
additional information in the LDAP server error logs.
----- amqzfula.c : 2489 -------------------------------------------------------
```

On Active Directory side these lines are recorded in log:

```
An account failed to log on.
Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       MYADSERVER$
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAINNAME
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
Logon Type:         3
Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       mybinduser
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAINNAME
Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC000006A
Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x280
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe
Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   MYADSERVER
    Source Network Address: 192.168.100.101
    Source Port:        55592
Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Here beleow is output of the command `DIS AUTHINFO(MY.AD.CONFIGURATION) ALL`

```
AMQ8566: Display authentication information details.
   AUTHINFO(MY.AD.CONFIGURATION)          AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP)
   ADOPTCTX(NO)                            DESCR( )
   CONNAME(192.168.100.100)                CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)
   CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL)                      CLASSGRP( )
   CLASSUSR( )                             FAILDLAY(1)
   FINDGRP(MEMBER)                         BASEDNG(OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us)
   BASEDNU( )
   LDAPUSER(CN=mybinduser,OU=System,OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us)
   LDAPPWD( )                              SHORTUSR(sAMAccountName)
   GRPFIELD( )                             USRFIELD( )
   AUTHORMD(SEARCHGRP)                     NESTGRP(NO)
   SECCOMM(NO)                             ALTDATE(2019-07-25)
   ALTTIME(08.14.20)
```

Here below is output from LdapAuthentication.jar tool:

```
java -jar LdapAuthentication.jar ldap://192.168.100.100:389 CN=mybinduser,OU=System,OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us mybinduserpassword OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us sAMAccountName adminusername adminpassword

@WMBL3: successful bind
@WMBL3: successfull search Starting Authentication Found the user, DN is CN=adminusername,OU=MyCompany,OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us
@WMBL3 : check if the password is correct
@WMBL3: successful authentication
@WMBL3 : Commands for WebUI ldap authentication :

1. mqsisetdbparms <INodeName> -n ldap::LDAP -u "CN=mybinduser,OU=System,OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us" -p mybinduserpassword

                                 Or

 mqsisetdbparms <INodeName> -n ldap::192.168.100.100 -u "CN=mybinduser,OU=System,OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us" -p mybinduserpassword

2. mqsichangeproperties <INodeName> -b webadmin -o server -n ldapAuthenticationUri -v \"ldap://192.168.100.100:389/OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us?sAMAccountName\"

3. mqsiwebuseradmin <INodeName> -c -u adminusername -x -r <sysrole  for eg: local userid >
```

Here below is qmanager log after I applied changes in my AUTHINFO what you suggested Jul 25.

```
AMQ5531: Error locating user or group in LDAP

EXPLANATION:
The LDAP authentication and authorization service has failed in the ldap_search
call while trying to find user or group 'wasadmin'. Returned count is 0.
Additional context is 'rc = 1 (Operations error)
[(&(objectClass=GROUP)(SAMACCOUNTNAME=wasadmin))]'.
ACTION: Specify the correct name, or fix the directory configuration. There may be
additional information in the LDAP server error logs.
```

This is myadgroup full DN: 
`CN=myadgroup,OU=System,OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us`

This is output of the setmqaut command with full group DN:

```
setmqaut -m MY.QUEUE.MANAGER -t qmgr -g 'CN=myadgroup,OU=System,OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us' +all
AMQ7047: An unexpected error was encountered by a command. Reason code is 2063.
```

And this is qmanager log after that command was executed:

```
AMQ5531: Error locating user or group in LDAP

EXPLANATION: The LDAP authentication and authorization service has failed in the ldap_search call while trying to find user or group 'CN=myadgroup,OU=System,OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us'.
Returned count is 0.
Additional context is 'rc = 1 (Operations error) [(objectClass=groupOfNames)]'. 
ACTION:
Specify the correct name, or fix the directory configuration. There may be
additional information in the LDAP server error logs.
```

If I try with `CLASSGRP(GROUP)` output of the `setmqaut` is:

```
AMQ7047: An unexpected error was encountered by a command. Reason code is 2063.
```

And qmqnager log is:

```
AMQ5531: Error locating user or group in LDAP

EXPLANATION: The LDAP authentication and authorization service has failed in the
ldap_search call while trying to find user or group
'CN=myadgroup,OU=System,OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us'.
Returned count is 0.
Additional context is 'rc = 1 (Operations error) [(objectClass=GROUP)]'.

ACTION:
Specify the correct name, or fix the directory configuration. There may be
additional information in the LDAP server error logs.
```

Below is my last configured authinfo object:

```
AMQ8566: Display authentication information details.   
AUTHINFO(MY.AD.CONFIGURATION)           AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP)   
ADOPTCTX(YES)                           DESCR( )   
CONNAME(192.168.100.100)                CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)   
CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL)                      CLASSGRP(group)   
CLASSUSR(USER)                          FAILDLAY(1)
FINDGRP(member)
BASEDNG(OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us)   
BASEDNU(OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us)   
LDAPUSER(CN=mybinduser,OU=System,OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us)
LDAPPWD( )                              SHORTUSR(sAMAccountName)   
GRPFIELD(sAMAccountName)                USRFIELD(sAMAccountName)   
AUTHORMD(SEARCHGRP)                     NESTGRP(NO)
SECCOMM(NO)                             ALTDATE(2019-08-07)
ALTTIME(08.44.40)
```

Comment: Two observations.  1. The current v9.0 is 9.0.0.7, i would suggest you update to this version.  2. The ldapuser on your AUTHINFO object should be in the form of a DN, ex `CN=mybinduser,OU=XYZ,DC=MYDOMAINNAME,DC=COM`.

Comment: Let me know if the `LDAPUSER` format is the problem.  I'll write up a quick answer.

Comment: Hi Josh, I tried LDAPUSER  with DN form, but it didn't help

Comment: Did the error change at all?

Comment: Update to version 9.0.0.7 also didn't help

Comment: Error is changed only in my console after I executed setmqaut -m MY.QUEUE.MANAGER -t qmgr -g myadgroup +all .  Now error is :AMQ7047: An unexpected error was encountered by a command. Reason code is 2063

Comment: What about this part `Additional context is 'rc = 87 (Bad search filter)
[(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(=myadgroup ))]'` is it t the same?

Comment: What does `DISPLAY QMSTATUS ALL` show?

Comment: This tool can help test that you have the correct parameters: [Using the LdapAuthentication.jar tool for troubleshooting LDAP authentication and the WebUI](https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2016/11/02/using-the-ldapauthentication-jar-tool-for-troubleshooting-ldap-authentication-and-the-webui/)

Comment: Additional context is 'rc = 87 (Bad search filter) [(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(=myadgroup ))]    this is same in qmanager log

Comment: DISPLAY QMSTATUS ALL
     1 : DISPLAY QMSTATUS ALL
AMQ8705: Display Queue Manager Status Details.
   QMNAME(MY.QUEUE.MANAGER                 STATUS(RUNNING)
   CONNS(23)                               CMDSERV(RUNNING)
   CHINIT(RUNNING)                         INSTNAME(Installation1)
   INSTPATH(/opt/mqm_v9)                   INSTDESC( )
   LDAPCONN(ERROR)                         STANDBY(NOPERMIT)
   STARTDA(2019-07-24)                     STARTTI(10.28.32)

Comment: I tried LdapAuthentication.jar tool and connection to AD was successful

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `DIS AUTHINFO(MY.AD.CONFIGURATION) ALL` to the question.  Please don't paste it in a comment.

Comment: DIS AUTHINFO(MY.AD.CONFIGURATION) ALL   output added to the question

Comment: Can you please also provide the `LdapAuthentication.jar` command that was successful?

Comment: LdapAuthentication.jar command  output added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the your output I noted that you did not set `LDAPPWD` which is used by MQ to authenticate the `LDAPUSER` that you specified.

This is supported by the windows error you provided:

```
Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       mybinduser
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAINNAME
Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
```

In the output of `LdapAuthentication.jar` it appears that you have the correct password available:

```
CN=mybinduser,OU=System,OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us mybinduserpassword
```

You can either specify the `LDAPPWD` or you can blank out your `LDAPUSER` and see if your AD allows anonymous bind (this is rare).

I noted that you have some other fields left blank that probably need to be filled in.  I also suggest you always use `ADOPTCTX(YES)`.

Below is my suggested updates to your `AUTHINFO` object:

```
ALTER AUTHINFO(MY.AD.CONFIGURATION) +
      AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP) +
      AUTHORMD(SEARCHGRP) +
      FINDGRP('member') +
      ADOPTCTX(YES) +
      CONNAME(192.168.100.100) +
      CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) +
      CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +
      CLASSGRP(GROUP) +
      CLASSUSR(USER) +
      FAILDLAY(1) +
      BASEDNG('OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us') +
      BASEDNU('OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us') +
      LDAPUSER('CN=mybinduser,OU=System,OU=Users,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us') +
      LDAPPWD(mybinduserpassword) +
      SHORTUSR(sAMAccountName) +
      GRPFIELD(sAMAccountName) +
      USRFIELD(sAMAccountName) +
      NESTGRP(NO) +
      SECCOMM(NO)
```

*Note I have not tested this against AD, but I have setup IIB to authenticate the WebUI/REST calls against AD and also took inspiration from two presentations/write ups from Mark Taylor from IBM:

- [MQ Integration with Directory Services - Presented at MQTC v2.0.1.6](https://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2016/MQ_Directory_Integration.pdf)
- [MQdev Blog: IBM MQ - Using Active Directory for authorisation in Unix queue managers](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/IBM_MQ_Using_Active_Directory_for_authorisation_in_Unix_queue_managers?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks Josh, I tried but without success. In qmanager log now I can see different error. AD Iog has same error. I  added qmanager log to your answer

Comment: New content should be edited into your question.   Please provide the full DN of `mygroup`.

Comment: I moved new error from qmanager log to my question. I also provided myadgroup full DN.

Comment: On that group is the `sAMAccountName` filled in with the short name?  If not what field on groups is filled in with a short group name?  Can you try `setmqaut -m MY.QUEUE.MANAGER -t qmgr -g 'CN=myadgroup,OU=System,OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=mycompany,DC=us' +all` and see if that is successful?

Comment: sAMAccountName is filled with groupname, and also fileds 'name', 'displayName' and 'cn' are filled with group name.

Comment: What is the `objectClass` of the group?  Can you edit the question and add the error when you run the `setmqaut` command with the full group DN?

Comment: Can you try with `CLASSGRP(GROUP)`?  The error shows `objectClass=groupOfNames` which i is the default if you leave `CLASSGRP` blank.

Comment: There are two entries for the objectClass. 'objectClass: top' and 'objectClass: group'. Error after setmqaut with full group DN is added to the question

Comment: I tried with CLASSGRP('GROUP'). Errors are added to my question.

Comment: Looks like you tried again with short group name,  I wanted you to try with full DN.

Comment: Sorry. Now I tried with full DN. qmqnager log is edited in my question

Comment: Can you check the domain control logs for associated errors?

Comment: domain controller logs are same like as in  my question

Comment: You mean you still get `Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password` for `mybinduser`?

Comment: Can you confirm you set the `LDAPUSER` and `LDAPPWD` to the same values that worked with `LdapAuthentication.jar` ?

Comment: I'm sure these are the same values i used for LdapAuthentication.jar

Comment: My AD admin only looks at event logs. Are there any other logs on the AD server? Is there a way to raise the logging level on AD (a kind of trace)?

Comment: Can you display your full authinfo object again and add it to the end of the question?   I don't know about AD logging level, but if the test jar could bind with the user and pass then why can MQ not?

Comment: During the last two weeks I tried many different configurations of the authinfo, and all were unsuccessful. Now I added my last configured authinfo object to the question.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that last week I successfully connected my queue manager to other AD server(test server installed few weeks before this one I am trying to connect to). I noticed one important detail regarded to the LDAPPWD
parameter when I display AUTHINFO object. In the authinfo for the test AD server LDAPPWD is with stars between parenthesis like this: 'LDAPPWD(********************************)', but in authinfo for the production AD server LDAPPWD is without stars
between parenthesis, as you can see in my last configured AUTHINFO object.

Comment: I don't know why is that. Only difference is in password length. Both passwords contains only letters and numbers.

Comment: The knowledge center states if it is non blank it will show up as *'s, so if it is blank MQ does not consider it filled in.

Comment: We tried to set production AD bind password to test AD bind user and IT DOES NOT WORK!!! 
I did a few tests on test AD with different passwords(different characters and lengths). Every password works fine except password for production AD bind user. 
This is ridiculous. It turns out that it doesn't work just with the specific password assigned to the bind user on production AD

Comment: How long is the password?  Does it contain any non-ascii characters (for example UTF8 double byte characters)?  Does a password with the same length but different characters work?

Comment: Password is 11 characters long. It doesn't contain non-ascii characters. Password with the same length but different characters works. This is similar example of the password 'Wm0A1Htj2zi'

Comment: I just checked and it appears limit is 32 characters: `MQ_LDAP_PASSWORD_LENGTH` = 32.

Comment: Does that "example" value fail?

Comment: I know for 32 characters limit. That 'example' password doesn't fail, it works.

Comment: I suggest you create a case with IBM, create a new qm, turn on trace, recreate the issue of setting `LDAPPWD` to the value you know will silently fail.  End the trace, then gather it up with runmqras and send it to IBM. Or the alternate suggestion, change the binduser's password. I would suggest the former.

Comment: We solved the problem by creating a second AD bind user with a different password. This user is only used for MQ.

Comment: Glad go hear you resolved it.   I hope my answer helped.   I can the information about ldappwd that were discussed in chat into my answer.

Comment: This is a specific situation where I work for the client who cannot report the problem to IBM. So I turned on the trace and collected logs. After converting them to txt files I can't find anything that would indicate a problem. Can you give me some guidance on how to analyze these trace logs?

Comment: After you able to find the password in the trace?  Did you use `dspmqtrc` to convert them to text?

Comment: I was unableto find password for mybinduser in trace logs. Yes I used dspmqtrc to convert bin to txt files